# Bomberman like game

Tags: game

I'm searching a game which is pretty like Bomberman. It would be great if it's an open source game, which can be modified, but this isn't a must have. It would be really cool to find costume parts, like in the Bomberman for Nintendo N64.

It would be great if this one can be installed under Windows 8 or above but a Linux one would be good enough too, as it could be installed in a VM.

**Requirements:**

- should be runnable on Windows 8 x64 and above
- Real 3D graphic is appreciated but good isometric would be good enough too
- it should provide a multiplayer mode (realtime)
- an offline / single player mode using a ki would be appreciated
- customizable characters using lootable equipment would be appreciated
- It should support Full-HD resolution
- there are no limitations on disc, cpu, memory or graphic power

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried it but there is an Open Source bomberman clone called [Bombr](http://www.pygame.org/project-BOMBR-2869-4660.html) written in pyGame so you will need both [python](http://python.org) and the [pygame libraries](http://www.pygame.org/download.shtml) both of which are available for Windows, OS-X and Linux.  The good news is installing them opens up the possibility of playing lots of other retro games that others have coded and of course of writing your own.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look at Crazy Arcade's Bomb and Bubbles (BnB) ([Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crazy_Arcade), [Official website](http://bnb.sdo.com/)):

- Microsoft Windows
- in Korean
- multiplayer mode (realtime)

[image]

Also, check out [List of Bomberman video games](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Bomberman_video_games)